# Textos a melhorar nas dicas das análises

Tags: bug, tradução, localização, filas-de-análise

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## 1) Ignorar ou Pular?

O texto no SO.com diz **Skip** (à nivel de informação).

Eu sou a favor de manter **Pular** para o botão e corrigir o texto, não gostaria que fosse **Ignorar** no lugar pois não me soa bem, parece que não é o real sentido da ação que se está executando.

Obs: para "Votos encerrados" e "Votos reabertos" está "Pular" tanto no botão como no texto..

## <strike>2) Feedback?</strike>

> **Comentar** para deixar um *feedback* construtivo ao autor.

Preferiria uma palavra em português. Não tenho certeza da palavra que usaria no lugar.

Sugestões: um *parecer* construtivo, uma *dica* construtiva, uma *informação* construtiva, um *comentário* construtivo.

Comment: A palavra em português pra _feedback_ que usamos é _retorno_. Não sei se ficaria melhor pois alguns termos de uso geral ou técnicos eu prefiro não traduzir. Pular é melhor que ignorar.